# Prefiltering of list items + some UI actions on client side. Can it be speeded up more?

Tags: jquery

is there a way of speeding-up this even more?

```
this.preFilter = function ($sourceSelector, text) {
    var regex = new RegExp(text, 'i');
    $sourceSelector.each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().match(regex)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).children().first().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).children().last().removeClass('addGroupMemberButtonClicked').addClass('addGroupMemberButton').button('option', 'icons', { primary: 'ui-icon-plusthick' });
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Now it takes about 0.5s on half-thousand of elements. The matter is I don't want to make additional AJAX request - i have tons of them already in my rich client UI. I am not keen of using children() and first/last selectors - they're not flexible in case layout would change in future. But when i was using find - it took 7s, that is unacceptable, of course...

UPDATE: decorating all those buttons with jQuery widgets was not a good idea, without applying button loop is 3 times faster. Besides, markup is not optimal - has some empty spans even if button has no text :( But it's not me, but designer, who creates layout. I can have a look at UI-related classes in markup, created by widget and just remove them. But it's not a proper way of doing things, i guess: in future those widget may change and class names will be different, etc.

HTML

```
<div style="width: auto; min-height: 2px; max-height: none; height: auto;" id="ui-id-28" class="addGroupMember ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" data-title="Add participant">
  <input value="" name="usersearch" class="userSearchField" placeholder="Search user name" type="search">
  <input value="" name="" class="userSearchButton" type="button">
  <ul class="userList">
    <li>
      <input value="**" name="Id" class="" disabled="disabled" data-is-key="True" type="hidden">Wvgtsnewp zhnu
      <button title="" role="button" class="addGroupMemberButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" type="button">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
          <span class="ui-button-text">
          <span class=""></span>
          <span class=""></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>and so still half of thousand items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Need a lot more context for anyone to help with this.

Comment: @charlietfl Related markup has been added. Thanks.